# Zip -x is not behaving as expected

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I'm trying to ignore a directory when creating a zip file. I am using this command:

```
zip -r  /home/username/Backups/HTML/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY.zip /home/username/public_html/ -x */home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads/* -x *log -x *.git* -x *.zip* -x *.gz* -x *.tar*
```

`$YEAR`, `$MONTH` and `$DAY` have all been defined earlier and function as expected.

I'm trying to ignore this directory and all its sub-directories and files:

```
/home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads
```

However, even though I have excluded it using `-x` flag, it is still backed up, as shown in the log:

```
adding: home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/file.jpg
```

How do I avoid doing this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Unix zip directory but excluded specific subdirectories](https://superuser.com/q/312301/173513), [how to exclude directories and file zipping a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/371579), [How to exclude a directory when zipping files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219101/56041), etc.

Answer (score -1):

You may use --exclude instead of -x. Typical command will look as follows.

```
zip -r  /home/username/Backups/HTML/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY.zip /home/username/public_html/ --exclude=*/home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads*
```